# Subsetting in R based on partial variable name and frequence

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a data.frame with the following layout:

```
Proteins          Mass
TBA|ZHU|TBA|GRE   331
ZHU|TBA|GRE       438
TBB|TBB|ZWB|GRE   355
ZWB|TBB           788
ZHU|HJL|GRE|LKO   968
GWT               836
```

Now, I want to subset all the rows where "Proteins" either contains "TBA" or "TBB" and where the occurrence of those equals 1. The output would look as follows:

```
Proteins          Mass
ZHU|TBA|GRE       438
ZWB|TBB           788
```

I am using

```
data <- df[(grep("TBA|TBB", df$Proteins),]
```

to subset the rows where either TBA or TBB is present, but I don´t know how to couple the subsetting to the occurence of those. Can anyone please help out?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried stringr::str_count()?

Answer (score 0):

stringr::str_count() would work.

```
df <- data.frame(proteins = c("TBA|ZHU|TBA|GRE", "ZHU|TBA|GRE"),
                 mass = runif(n=2))

df[stringr::str_count(df$proteins, "TBA|TBB") == 1, ]

     proteins      mass
2 ZHU|TBA|GRE 0.7186705
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `strsplit` by pipe to create wide format columns and then `reshape` to long for subsetting by unique word count calculated using `ave`:

**Assign** new Protein## columns

```
# SPLIT BY PIPE 
protein_list <- strsplit(as.character(df$Proteins), "\\|")
max_cols <- max(sapply(protein_list, length))

# FILL NAs INTO LIST
protein_list <- lapply(protein_list, function(p) {
  q <- rep(NA, max_cols)
  q[seq_along(p)] <- p
  return(q)
})

# ASSIGN NEW COLUMNS
df[paste0("protein_", 1:max_cols)] <- do.call(rbind, protein_list)
df
#          Proteins Mass protein_1 protein_2 protein_3 protein_4
# 1 TBA|ZHU|TBA|GRE  331       TBA       ZHU       TBA       GRE
# 2     ZHU|TBA|GRE  438       ZHU       TBA       GRE      <NA>
# 3 TBB|TBB|ZWB|GRE  355       TBB       TBB       ZWB       GRE
# 4         ZWB|TBB  788       ZWB       TBB      <NA>      <NA>
# 5 ZHU|HJL|GRE|LKO  968       ZHU       HJL       GRE       LKO
# 6             GWT  836       GWT      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
```

**Reshape** wide to long

```
# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG
rdf <- reshape(df, varying = paste0("protein_", 1:max_cols), times = paste0("protein_", 1:max_cols),
               v.names = "value", timevar = "protein", idvar = c("Proteins", "Mass"),
               new.row.names = 1:1E4, direction = "long")

# CALCUATE UNIQUE WORD OCCURRENCE
rdf$count <- with(rdf, ave(Mass, Proteins, value, 
                           FUN=function(x) max(length(x), na.rm=TRUE)))

rdf  
#           Proteins Mass   protein value count
# 1  TBA|ZHU|TBA|GRE  331 protein_1   TBA     2
# 2      ZHU|TBA|GRE  438 protein_1   ZHU     1
# 3  TBB|TBB|ZWB|GRE  355 protein_1   TBB     2
# 4          ZWB|TBB  788 protein_1   ZWB     1
# 5  ZHU|HJL|GRE|LKO  968 protein_1   ZHU     1
# 6              GWT  836 protein_1   GWT     1
# 7  TBA|ZHU|TBA|GRE  331 protein_2   ZHU     1
# 8      ZHU|TBA|GRE  438 protein_2   TBA     1
# 9  TBB|TBB|ZWB|GRE  355 protein_2   TBB     2
# 10         ZWB|TBB  788 protein_2   TBB     1
# 11 ZHU|HJL|GRE|LKO  968 protein_2   HJL     1
# 12             GWT  836 protein_2  <NA>   836
# 13 TBA|ZHU|TBA|GRE  331 protein_3   TBA     2
# 14     ZHU|TBA|GRE  438 protein_3   GRE     1
# 15 TBB|TBB|ZWB|GRE  355 protein_3   ZWB     1
# 16         ZWB|TBB  788 protein_3  <NA>   788
# 17 ZHU|HJL|GRE|LKO  968 protein_3   GRE     1
# 18             GWT  836 protein_3  <NA>   836
# 19 TBA|ZHU|TBA|GRE  331 protein_4   GRE     1
# 20     ZHU|TBA|GRE  438 protein_4  <NA>   438
# 21 TBB|TBB|ZWB|GRE  355 protein_4   GRE     1
# 22         ZWB|TBB  788 protein_4  <NA>   788
# 23 ZHU|HJL|GRE|LKO  968 protein_4   LKO     1
# 24             GWT  836 protein_4  <NA>   836
```

**Subset** by unique word count

```
# FILTER BY ONE OCCURRENCE
sub_df <- subset(rdf, value %in% c("TBB", "TBA") & count == 1)

sub_df
#       Proteins Mass   protein value count
# 8  ZHU|TBA|GRE  438 protein_2   TBA     1
# 10     ZWB|TBB  788 protein_2   TBB     1
```